# ng-repeat doesn't update when item added from component directive

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have problem of my code but couldn't find that,I updated an array but it doesn't update in my main view

here my code

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = [];

    $scope.adduser = function (fuser, luser) {
        var name = { fname: fuser, lname: luser }
       // debugger;
        $scope.user.push(name);

    };
```

```
<div ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h3>User Info</h3>
       <userinfo></userinfo>
       <div ng-repeat="name in user">
           {{name.fname}}
       </div>
    </div>
```

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="MainCtrl">


First Name : <input type="text" ng-model="fname">
<br> Last Name : <input type="text" ng-model="lname">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="adduser(fname,lname)">Add</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: No, There are no errors

Comment: In your example you doesn't call function `$scope.adduser` - are you sure that you have any `user` in `$scope.user `array?

Comment: I call that method in directive

Comment: I think that this is the reason - your view doesn't know about new data because you trigger them from another scope.  Did you try add `$scope.$apply()` under `$scope.user.push(name);` ? Here you can find example http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

If this work we should look for another solution, because you shouldn't use $apply in normal angularJS flow.

Comment: Include the code for the directive. It likely uses isolate scope so that it can't access the `$scope.addUser` function in the parent controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the variable in the directive,

```
<userinfo user='user'></userinfo>
```

and the directive as,

```
scope: {
   user: '='
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`controllerAs` syntax makes available your controller function `this`(context) accessible via its alias, here it is `c`. As you're using `controllerAs` syntax, Your binding values should be bounded to controller function context (`this`). You should be avoid using `$scope` in controller in `controllerAs` approach. Even while calling `adduser` method call it by controller alias `c.adduser`

**Code**

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function ($http) {
    var c= this;
    c.user = [];
    c.adduser = adduser;

    function adduser(fuser, luser) {
        var name = { fname: fuser, lname: luser }
       // debugger;
        c.user.push(name)
    };
})
```

Comment: earlier I coded without using  'controllerAs' syntax, how could i code without that

Comment: @Lakmi what do you mean by that.. I'd never prefer to go back to use `$scope` in controller. As using `controllerAs` syntax make you 1 small step closer to angular migration..

Comment: I used your code but it didn't work for me.I update my code this is the way i coded before.that one also not working

Comment: @Lakmi what do you mean by *didn't work*? may be you missed to change usage of `adduser` to `c.adduser()`